# How can a camera capture the movement of light (in slow motion) if the electronics operate below the speed of light?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, electronics, camera

A while back I saw the MIT produced video where they show their camera capturing 1-trillion frames per second and show the light moving around a coke bottle in slow motion.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtsXgODHMWk

How can a camera capture a high enough frames-per-second to catch the slow-motion movement of light (for lack of better description) if electricity operates somewhere below the speed of light? I.e. how do the electronics process something *above* the speed of light?

Comment: The "camera" is not really an ordinary camera capturing frames on a cmos chip [MIT Camera](https://news.mit.edu/2011/trillion-fps-camera-1213)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out @Triatticus. For others interested, from the article linked above: "The system relies on a recent technology called a streak camera, deployed in a totally unexpected way... because the electric field is changing very rapidly, it deflects the electrons corresponding to late-arriving photons more than it does those corresponding to early arriving ones. The image produced by the camera is thus two-dimensional... the other dimension, corresponding to the degree of deflection, is time."

Comment: To be fair someone might be able to come along and expand on how this actually generates a video since that article isn't highly technical.

Comment: Thanks for the article, that explains it for me; they can capture tiny portions of the final image at a time so they have to repeat the light pulse and move the camera each repetition and then composite it all together in the end; so it indeed is NOT operating the same way as a traditional 'camera' as I would think of it

Comment: The camera that they use to create these movies is a [streak camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streak_camera)

Comment: Re, "...they have to repeat the light pulse..." This is _somewhat, slightly_ similar to how one can use a [_stroboscope_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscope) to "slow down" the motion of a spinning wheel or a cycling machine.